# Count all elements, display results with unique values and counts

Tags: jquery, count, distinct

I have a table with a column for username.  Beside the table I want to list all the usernames individually with a count of how many times they appear in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yaj)

**HTML**

```
<div class="username">jsmith</div>
<div class="username">jsmith</div>
<div class="username">bruth</div>
<div class="username">bruth</div>
<div class="username">jsmith</div>
<div class="username">jsmith</div>
<div class="username">bdole</div>
<div class="username">bdole</div>
<br />
<div id="result"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var divs = []
$('.username').each(function() {
    var uid = $(this).html();
    if ($.inArray(uid, divs) < 0) {
        divs.push(uid);
    }
}).promise().done(function() {
    $.each(divs, function(index, value) {
        var sel = '.username:contains("' + value + '")';
        var n = $(sel).length;
        $('#result').append('<div>' + value + ' x' + n + '</div>');
    });
});
```